# Is there a way to change the VBA code based on a value of a particular cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose cell A1 contains a folder address.
Now I want a VBA code which can pick this folder address and use it as a path to run the whole code.

This is my VBA code:

```
Sub GetSheets()
    Path = "" 'Folder address has to be added here

    File name = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
    Do while.........

End Sub
```

I am looking for a VBA code which picks the value from cell A1 and add to the Path.

Comment: Note: You cannot have spaces in a variable name, so you will probably want to use something like `sFileName` instead of `File name`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, this should help.

```
Path = Range("A1").value
File name = Dir(Path & "*.xls") Do while.........
```